# OLA Money API Hash Code Error

Tags: ruby, hash

While integrating OLA Money API, when I hit url with all parameter am getting error

> "Hash Code mismatched"

The main problem is when we send  generated hash code through url, then last 2 characters of hash key `==` are changed into `%3D%3D`. Could you please give me solution of this.

Both Hash key are given below:

Generated Hash Key before URL-------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
eyJjb21tYW5kIjoiZGViaXQiLCJhY2Nlc3NUb2tlbiI6IjN1NDFwODJ1VDEiLCJ1bmlxdWVJZCI6IjEyMzQ1Nk9MNTY0Nzg4OSIsImNvbW1lbnRzIjoib2RldFgiLCJ1ZGYiOiI4dkJkZiIsImhhc2giOiJjODkzZTFjMWViZTQ1MTliMTUzOGE1NTEyNTUzMzRjNGRlNjZiNWRiNDQ4OWI1MTdlN2MxN2RhYzM4YWMwNTA3MGY1ZDQ3MDBiNjRlMTUyMTUyYzg5NWVlYzFhMDYyMGYzMTFlNzkyMDYzNzk5OThjZDQ2ZGE0ZDkxMzRiYzEzZSIsInJldHVyblVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cucnVwbGVlZGV2bG9wbWVudC5jb20vc2VydmljZS93ZWJzZXJ2aWNlc192MDMvb2xhbW9uZXkvb2xhUmVzcG9uc2UucGhwIiwibm90aWZpY2F0aW9uVXJsIjoiaHR0cDovL3d3dy5ydXBsZWVkZXZsb3BtZW50LmNvbS9zZXJ2aWNlL3dlYnNlcnZpY2VzX3YwMy9vbGFtb25leS9vbGFOb3RpZnkucGhwIiwiYW1vdW50IjoxLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6IklOUiIsImNvdXBvbkNvZGUiOiIifQ==
```

---

Generated Hash Key in URL--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
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%3D%3D
```

---

I look forward to solution from you,

Answer (score 2):

Issue here is - one of the Hash is getting URL encoded. Easiest way is to URL decode both the strings and then match. Here:

```
require 'uri'
h1 = "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"
h2 = "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%3D%3D"
h1 == h2 
# => false
URI.unescape(h1) == URI.unescape(h2)
# => true
```

Comment: Thanks shivam, but the last two characters of hash key is == and  changing on ola server while we post the two parameter (1. Hash key, 2. Phone no. ) on the ola server by GET method in php. What will be solution in that case??

Comment: @SumitJaiswal I dont get your question. In my answer I'm URL-decoding input string. So even if you have `=` or  `%3D`, they both will get decoded to `=` before comparison.